# How to serialize Dates into HashMap?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I have a use case where I get the object as  a json string and consecutively needs to transform it into a HashMap. My code is as follows:

```
public Map<String, Object> toMap(String jsonString) {
  Gson gson = new Gson();

  Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {
  }.getType();
  Map<String, Object> mapped = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
  return mapped;
}
```

The date value I get from jsonString is `"date": "2018-07-29T23:52:35.814Z"` but upon serialization into HashMap, the "date" value is a String and not a Date object. Is there a way around it? Even solutions where Gson is not used is welcome

Sample jsonString is as follows:

```
{
    "id": "1351",
    "date": "2018-07-30T00:32:31.564Z",
    "university": "US",
    "typeofwork": "Report",
    "title": "Thesis title",
    "subject": "Masters",
    "noofwords": "123"
}
```

To clarify, I am not getting any errors with the serialization/deserialization per se. I just want the `date` value to be of type `java.util.Date` such that a validation of `if(map.get("date") instanceOf java.util.Date)` will return true

Comment: Can we see all of your raw JSON?  Keep in mind your *date* `String` can be parsed into an `Instant` without having to change anything.

Comment: which format you want to get in hasmap?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the whole json. But I am not having problems with the other fields as they are all parsed into `String` inside the Map which is correct. I am just having problems with this `date` field which isn't exactly parsed into a `java.util.Date` object

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe: surely you can create and show a mock but valid JSON, one that shows how the date is represented, as well as your [mcve] code attempt to deserialize it

Comment: Use `Instant` instead of `Date`, and then you're free to call `LocalDate.ofInstant` on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have known exactly the property "date" is a Date, after parsing from Json, you can try somethiing like:

```
String dateStr = mapped.get("date");
mapped.put("date",new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").parse(dateStr));
```

If you don't want to do it manually, simply define a class that matches your Json object format (with the "date" field declared as a Date object), then:

```
Gson g = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("your date format").create();
NewClass obj = g.fromJson(jsonStr, NewClass.class);
```

Gson will parse the date string follow the format in setDateFormat() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using customDeserialzer class in Jackson:

```
public class CustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer {
@Override
public Object deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    if(p.getCurrentName().equals("date")){
        try {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS").parse(p.getText());
        }catch (Exception ex){
        }
        return p.getText();
    }
    return p.getText();
}
}
```

Then parse like it:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    String json = "{\"date\": \"2018-07-29T23:52:35.814Z\"}";
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule().addDeserializer(String.class, new CustomDeserializer());
    objectMapper.registerModule(module);
    hashMap = objectMapper.readValue(json,new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>>(){});
    hashMap.entrySet().parallelStream().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getValue()));
```

Comment: I am also not getting any error, but I want the "date" value to be of type `java.util.Date` such that when a validation of `if(hashmap.get("date") instanceOf java.util.Date)` will return true

Comment: you can do it like this